# GDAL python scripts not importing in Linux

Tags: python, gdal, linux

I'm new to both GDAL and Linux. I have installed GDAL on my Linux mint PC. I am able to use regular GDAL commands in the terminal, but when I use python based commands,such as `gdal_calc.py` I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal_calc.py", line 51, in <module>
    from osgeo import gdal
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    _gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libspatialite.so.7: undefined symbol: freexl_version
```

I get the same error when I try `from osgeo import gdal` in a Python session. I am presuming that this has something to do with the locations of the gdal python scripts, or something related to spatialite (although I am not sure what spatialite has to do with this command). I also have QGIS and PostGIS installed, which presumably could cause some conflicts.

I have searched numerous sources, but can't find the cause of this error. I wonder if someone might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: What happens if you type `import gdal` in a python session?

Comment: I get the same error using 'import gdal'. In an idle session, if I type 'from osgeo import gdal', I get a ===RESTART:  Shell=== message, then when inputting 'import gdal' again, I get the same initial error.

Comment: Can you run the gdal utilities using subprocess.call()? This could be a temporary hack if you don't have time on your side

Comment: Would this help this particular problem. I'm not trying to write a python script. I'm just trying to use the GDAL python commands (gdal_calc.py; gdal_edit.py, etc) in the terminal. If they don't work in the terminal, I'm not sure they would work from a subprocess.call().

Comment: I misunderstood. Yeah, I don't think subprocess would work. Where is your python installation from? I get mine via anaconda/miniconda and its always worked fine. Miniconda/anaconda has the added benefit of allowing you to add other packages (gdal utilities, i.e gdal_translate) easily

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @NathanThomas. I have tried the installation via Anaconda, but there seems to be a conflict between the version of numpy installed with Anaconda, and the numpy associated with gdal. When running `conda install gdal`, I get the following error `UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - gdal -> numpy 1.8* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.` When running `conda info numpy', I get a list of versions including numpy 1.8.

Comment: @David You may be able to get around some of this by installing the python3 version (I assume that you installed the python 2.7 version?). You can use 'anaconda search -t conda gdal' to search for a compatible gdal version

Comment: Thanks for your help @NathanThomas. I installed python 3 with anaconda, but still not having much luck. I think it may be a case of re-installing everything associated with Python. To save time, I have installed OSGEO live, which has so far met my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the command directly (i.e ~/gdal_edit.py ) or are you passing the the script to the correct interpreter (i.e ~/bin/python3 gdal_edit.py)
If I just run ~/gdal_edit.py I get a very similar error:

```
~/bin$ gdal_edit.py
Traceback (most recent call last):File "~/bin/gdal_edit.py", line 34, in <module> from osgeo import gdal
  File "~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
_gdal = swig_import_helper()
  File "~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/__init__.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_gdal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.py", line 7, in <module>
__bootstrap__()
  File "~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
ImportError: ~/lib/python3.6/site-packages/GDAL-2.2.1-py3.6- 
linux-x86_64.egg/osgeo/_gdal.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicode_AsUTF8String
```

But when I pass it the script to the interpreter:

```
  sguinn@zoot:~/bin$ ~/bin/python3 gdal_edit.py
Usage: gdal_edit [--help-general] [-ro] [-a_srs srs_def] [-a_ullr ulx uly lrx lry]
             [-tr xres yres] [-unsetgt] [-a_nodata value] [-unsetnodata]
             [-offset value] [-scale value]
             [-unsetstats] [-stats] [-approx_stats]
             [-gcp pixel line easting northing [elevation]]*
             [-unsetmd] [-oo NAME=VALUE]* [-mo "META-TAG=VALUE"]*  datasetname

Edit in place various information of an existing GDAL dataset.
```

It works as expected. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for that. I have actually reinstalled my distribution recently. I will test this once I have installed gdal.